# NodeJS: Cannot start connect-redis with Express 4.12.2

Tags: node.js, session, express, redis

I am using express 4.12.2, express-session 1.11.1, & connect-redis 1.4.7. When running the following code with `NODE_ENV=production npm start`:

```
var session = require('express-session');
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);

app.use(session({
  store: new RedisStore(options),
  secret: 'keyboard cat'
}));
```

I receive the following error:

```
 var Store = connect.session.Store;
                            ^
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'Store' of undefined
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1.4.7` is a pretty old version of `connect-redis`. The signature has changed since that version. Before it accepted a `connect` object, but since the 2.0 update with express 4 it now accepts a `session` object. Your code is already using the new signature so for this to work all you should need to do is update your `package.json`

```
...
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "connect-redis": "^2.3.0"
}
...
```

and/or update the module in place:

```
npm install connect-redis
```

Comment: after update connect-redis, the error become Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined